When searching for strings in a dataframe via lambda function, how do I resolve the IndexError if no results are found in any column or row?
This question is piggy-backing off of a previous question that I asked regarding searching though a dataframe and printing out rows that contained a certain string, but not duplicating the output if the string value was found in more than one column.
Original question HERE.
The solution offered works unless the term being searched is not found. If not found I receive the following error:
Enter search term: foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\Python Stuff\Py Projects\App\DF_Search\fileSearch.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(tabulate(df_f, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple_grid', maxcolwidths=[None, None, 100]))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python\Lib\site-packages\tabulate\__init__.py", line 2054, in tabulate
    num_cols = len(list_of_lists[0])
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

The data I am using is in the table below:



Column 1
Column 2
Column 3




ABC-12345
Bill
Win


ABC-12346
Tom
Window


ABC-12347
Matt
Red



Not necessarily clean code, but I'm trying building dataframes from google sheets for the first time, so forgive me.
searchterm = input("Enter search term: ")
    sheet1_name = 'MySheetName' 
    sheet1_id = 'MyGoogleSheetID' 
    sheet1_url = f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet1_id}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet1_name}'
    df = pd.read_csv(sheet1_url)
    # this is the code that was provided in my previous question that works as expected when a string is found
    df = df[df.map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) and searchterm.lower() in x.lower()).any(axis=1)]
    print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple_grid', maxcolwidths=[None, None, 100]))

If a string is found anywhere in the dataframe the output is as expected.
When the searchterm is not found the expectation is for nothing to happen, although I would like there to be a printout of "No results."
I have tried adding an if statement which still shows the IndexError but it may not be in the correct position:
df_f = df_f[df_f.map(lambda x: isinstance(x, str) and searchterm.lower() in x.lower()).any(axis=1)]
if searchterm in searchterm.lower():
    print(tabulate(df_f, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple_grid', maxcolwidths=[None, None, 100]))
else:
    print('nope')


The df is being created properly, yeah? Then remove the read_csv stuff and just provide the df as code. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples. And please use minimal data. This seems to be more than necessary.

I just skimmed the previous question and I don't see tabulate even mentioned, so how is that question related?

OK, after reading it thoroughly, I see the problem now: e-motta's answer is not very good. I'll see if I can write you a better one.

@wjandrea I added tabulate after the fact to pretty up the output since the live data I am viewing has large amounts of hand-typed information that takes up a large portion of the terminal and does not display well without using something like jupyter or outputting to an html table. I did that in this example only to clean up my view while troubleshooting.
Also, thank you for the resource and info on using minimal data.

Why did you do searchterm in searchterm.lower()? That doesn't seem to make any sense

You can just check if the DF is empty before using the contents:
if df.empty:
    print('not found')
else:
    print(tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='simple_grid', maxcolwidths=[None, None, 100]))


I appreciate the answer. I was not aware that df.empty would mean that the df was empty of that string in this scenario. I thought that would be to check if nothing was contained in the dataframe. That did work. Thank you.

It does check if the DF is empty and this will be the case after your lambda selection if the string is not there and hence tabulate error.
